# Electron doesn't respect `webPreferences.defaultFontFamily`?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a little piece of `Electron` code that was wrote at the 2.X period. It's an un-packaged local editor/debugger that make heavy use of the (default) `monospace` font family, and it run quite well through all the `nodejs` / `Electron` major/minor version upgrades, until recently.

Before `Electron` 5.0 the font was "correct", no specific option was needed and I believe the actual font used was `Courier New` which is the default;

But after the recent 5.0 upgrade the actual font used suddenly became `NSimSun` (A Chinese font, probably because this is a Chinese version of Windows).

I searched the document, found the `webPreferences.defaultFontFamily` entry and tried all kinds of font string on its `.monospace` with no avail, Electron insist on using `NSimSun` as monospace unless I explicitly specify `font-family` in browser window CSS.

Am I missing something?

Here's the code that define and open the browser window:

```
winMain=new electron.BrowserWindow({
    "width":960,
    "height":600,
    "minWidth":800,
    "minHeight":500,
    "backgroundColor":"#FFF",
    "center":false,
    "icon":__dirname+"/static/logo.png",
    "webPreferences":{
        "preload":path.join(__dirname,"preload.js"),
        "defaultFontFamily":{
            "monospace":"Consolas"
            // or "Noto Sans" or "'Noto Sans'" or "Courier New" or "'Courier New'"
        },
        "defaultEncoding":"UTF-8"
    }
});
// winMain.loadFile("index.html");
winMain.loadURL(url.format({
    "protocol":"file",
    "slashes":true,
    "pathname":path.join(__dirname,"index.html")
}));
```